# Make a html text loop based on sql

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I am trying to create something like:

```
Start in table ID "14"
IF the variable is = NOT NULL
print: name：value
jump onto next table entry
repeat until it has happened 21 times.
```

So far no luck. I have tried creating an array like so:

```
$array = $db->queryA('SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemId = 101');
```

But I can't communicate with it as a string. If I refer to to a value like `$name = $array[0]["name"];` I can extract the value. But even a simple foreach loop like

```
foreach($array as $val) {
print $val;
}
```

wont work. Can anybody help me to as of what I am doing wrong?

Also, the string looks something like this from var_dump:

```
array (size=1)
     0 => 
         array (size=57)
            'itemId' => string '101' (length=3)
            'name' => string 'Berry' (length=10)
            'level' => string '2' (length=1)
            'icon' => string 'images/items/101.jpg' (length=20)
            'max_qua' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: Is the method `queryA` a typo? Are you using the mysqli class for establishing the database connection?

Comment: I had someone help me set it up. If I use just "query" it don't work at all, if I use queryA it works. Don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
'Column1: ' . $val['column1']. ', Column2: '. $val['column2']
```

?

The column name extracted out of SQL should be the key of the array, and the value, the value. It may depend on what classes you're using to query the DB.

Edit to previous:

As the returned array is associative, in a foreach loop, try something like the following:

```
foreach($array as $name => $val) {
print $name . ' : ' . $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, $value is an array, each one is a record from the table in key value pair where the key is the column in the table and the value is the value of that column in that record.
$array looks something like this:

```
$array = [0 => 
             ['itemId' => '101', 
              'name' => 'Item Name', 
              'level' => '2', 
              'icon' => 'images/items/101.jpg', 
              'max_qua' => '0'
              ]
          ];
```

In your loop you will want something like this:

```
foreach($array as $val) {
    print $val['itemId'];
}
```

In my array example, it will print '101' for the first record. 
I'm assuming you probably have more records there but I'm going off of the example you provided in comments.

I hope this helps

EDIT: I edited this to use the example data which the OP provided in comments.

Comment: My array looks something like

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=57)
      'itemId' => string '101' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'Item Name' (length=10)
      'level' => string '2' (length=1)
      'icon' => string 'images/items/101.jpg' (length=20)
      'max_qua' => string '0' (length=1)

But if I try to write print $val['0']; I get a php error undefined offset...

Comment: You need $val['itemId'] because $val itself in the loop is equal to $array[0] (in the first instance of the loop). 
I'll edit my comment to fit with your given array example.

Comment: Oh. I just realized. It is printing all items in itemId, aka 101, 102, 103 etc. Right? So how do I manage to write name, level, icon etc instead?
Also, with your code it prints "itemId", not 101 :(